# Salesforce: Log in as other user

Tags: user, servicecloud, sales-cloud

I am having issues logging in as another user. I am able to log in as all other users with the same profile except for 1 particular user. Any ideas why that might be the case?

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is in sandbox.

Comment: Basic trouble shooting: 1. is that user active? 2. has that user granted login access to you i.e. do you see login link against his user name in setup area when you go to user's list page?

Comment: Are you getting an error? Are you sure the User is Active and non-frozen?

Comment: The user is non-frozen and is an active user.

Comment: I do not see the use login link against his name. The user mentioned having trouble login in. He received a dancing snowman when he tried logging in. I tried logging in as him but noticed that the link was not available next to his name.

Comment: Ok, it clarify the situation, that user has not granted login access to you(as org admin) hence you can't login. Dancing snowman in sandbox look like winter 17 release animation, do you have lightning experience enabled in your sandbox?

Comment: Amit, correct. I am a system administrator.  The user is also a system administrator that I just added. The user tried logging in but had issues when trying to log in. We are using lightning experience.

Comment: I think he is having trouble even on first login. First load of lightning experience is bit flow due to loading of heavy js libraries and that's where you see those animations(dancing snowman), ask him to grab a coffee and see the show for few seconds, I believe he will not be disappointed. Until he login at least once and grant you login access you can't login as him. You may ask him to try another browser as well(Chrome preferred).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please follow below instructions to [Enable the "Organization Admins Can Login as Any User" feature](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Enabling-Organization-Admins-Can-Login-as-Any-User):

> **Enable the "Organization Admins Can Login as Any User" feature**
>
> With this feature enabled, System Administrators can log in as any user in their organization without asking internal end-users to grant login access. Before you request this feature, review two pieces of documentation:
>
> - [Control Login Access](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=controlling_login_access.htm&language=en_US) for steps to control whether all users will
>     be asked to grant login access.
> - [Grant Login Access](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=granting_login_access.htm&language=en_US) for steps to    manually grant login access
>     on a per-user basis.
>
> **How to enable the "Organization Admins Can Login as Any User" feature**
>
> If your org uses Summer '15 or later, use the steps under "Enable Organization Admins Can Login As Any User."
>   If your org was upgraded from Professional Edition to Enterprise Edition, use the steps under "Request feature enablement from Salesforce Support."
>
> **Manually enable "Organization Admins Can Login as Any User"**
>
> 1. Click Setup
> 2. Under "Administer," select Security Controls | Login Access Policies.
> 3. Select Administrators Can Log in as Any User.
> 4. Click Save.
>
> If don't have access to the feature and your organization isn't Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, or Developer Edition, vote for the enhancement request on the IdeaExchange. If your organization is one of these editions, check with your System Administrator to activate the access permissions on your profile.
>
> **Request feature enablement from Salesforce Support**
>
> 1. Have a System Administrator create a case with Salesforce Customer Support.
> 2. In the case details, include:
>
>    - Your business case or justification.
>    - Your organization ID where you want the feature to be enabled.
>    - The text "Feature requested: Enable Org Admins to log in as any user
>        without having access granted by the users​"

Answer (score 3):

**Verify if that user is active** by navigating to Setup > Administration Setup > Manage Users > Users. Locate your user in list and verify Active column is checked.

**Verify if user has granted you login access** by navigating to Setup > Administration Setup > Manage Users > Users. Locate your user in list and verify if you see "Login" link in "Action" column(first column).

If either of these is not correct you can't login as that user.

If user is InActive you can activate that user if you are an org admin by editing user and selecting "Active" checkbox.

If user has not granted your login access you can ask him to do so by navigating to Setup > Personal Setup > My Personal Information > Grant Login Access.